# Flexbox Spacing/Responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox, spacing

I've been trying to figure out the issue for hours. I've tried to use

```
 .about_container {justify-content: space-evenly;}
```

However, it doesn't add any spacing between the child items. Also, the items do not adjust size. I've tried adding flex-flow, flex-basis, and flex-shrink/grow but none of them make any difference. I'm also having issues getting the images to be a specific size while also being responsive.

I would appreciate any advice!

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    
    max-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(2019-12-11-mountain-day-featured-01.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.about_container {
    display: flex;
    color: #A3DAE3;
    background-color: #784C87;
    box-shadow: -10px -10px 15px #A3DAE3 inset;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    
}

#about_jason {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#about_sam {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#about_mike {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.about_container img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    object-fit: scale-down;
}

article {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#about_mike a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #450175;
}

#about_mike a:hover {
    color: #89A1C9;
}


footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

#links li {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#links li:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    html {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .about_container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    article {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .about_jason > h2 {
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    #about_mike a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #450175;
    
    }
    
    #about_mike a:hover {
        color: #784C87;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

        <div class="menu-wrap">
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
            <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
            <div class="menu">
              <div>
                <div>
                  <ul id="links">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="sharethis-inline-follow-buttons"></div>
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <div class="about_container">
            <div id="about_jason">
                <h2>Jason R.</h2>
                    <img src="90528548_10213477312766132_4964276883236585472_n.jpg" />
                    <p>Hey guys! My name is Jason. I graduated with my Associates of 
                      Applied Science degree in Computer Programming at Minnesota State 
                      Community and Technical college. I am now a Computer Science major 
                      at Davenport University. I work on both the front-end and back-end
                      within our small team. Outside of work, I enjoy playing video games, 
                      biking, hiking, programming and learning about anything and everything! 
                      I look forward to working with you!</p>
              </div>
              <div id="about_mike">
                    <h2>Michael J.</h2>
                    <img src="Mike.jpg"/>
                     <p>Hey there! My name is Mike. I live in Montrose, 
                       Colorado where I remotely work with Jason and Sam. 
                       I am a self-taught graphic designer/illustrator. 
                       For several years, I have developed a strong graphic 
                       design portfolio and have a collection of my journey 
                       over the years on my own personal Wordpress at 
                       <a href="www.mikeyajonesdesign.wordpress.com">my wordpress</a>. 
                       I am advanced in Adobe InDesign, Illustrator, and 
                       Photoshop. Outside of work, I enjoy working on digital 
                       art, reading, photography, and teaching myself how to program. 
                       I am currently learning web development and python. I look 
                       forward to working with my team and I look forward to working 
                       with our clients we work with.</p>
                </div>
              <div id="about_sam">
                    <h2>Samantha K.</h2>
                    <img src="cropped_profile_picture.jpg"/>
                    <p>Hi everyone! My name is Samantha K. I started as a self 
                      taught designer and am now making the big move to pursue 
                      a degree in web design. I have experience in affinity designer, 
                      html and css. I have a beautiful 2 year old daughter, Emily, and 
                      a one year old puppy, Tobi. I live in Clifton, Colorado with my 
                      fiance, my daughter, our best friend and our dog. I enjoy bike rides, 
                      swimming, movies, photography, writing and creating digital art. 
                      I look forward to learning, gaining experience and working with my 
                      team to create beautiful designs.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here.  you have given the images the width and height values to remain the same in all sizes.

```
  .about_container img {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      object-fit: scale-down;
    }
```

I created a single class for each person div (about). and I gave each picture the width property as 350 px. instead of giving a fixed width height value to the images, I added the properties display block, width 100%. So they will always adjust themselves according to it, no matter how much the container width is.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(2019-12-11-mountain-day-featured-01.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.about_container {
  display: flex;
  color: #A3DAE3;
  background-color: #784C87;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 15px #A3DAE3 inset;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.about {
  width: 350px;
}

#about_jason {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#about_sam {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#about_mike {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.about_container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

article {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#about_mike a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #450175;
}

#about_mike a:hover {
  color: #89A1C9;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

#links li {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#links li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  html {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .about_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  article {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .about_jason>h2 {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
  #about_mike a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #450175;
  }
  #about_mike a:hover {
    color: #784C87;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
    <div class="hamburger">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul id="links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sharethis-inline-follow-buttons"></div>
  <h1>About Us</h1>
  <div class="about_container">
    <div id="about_jason" class="about">
      <h2>Jason R.</h2>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/72/1d/13/721d13848e02189b9c7aed0d27ae433a.jpg" />
      <p>Hey guys! My name is Jason. I graduated with my Associates of Applied Science degree in Computer Programming at Minnesota State Community and Technical college. I am now a Computer Science major at Davenport University. I work on both the front-end
        and back-end within our small team. Outside of work, I enjoy playing video games, biking, hiking, programming and learning about anything and everything! I look forward to working with you!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about_mike" class="about" >
      <h2>Michael J.</h2>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/72/1d/13/721d13848e02189b9c7aed0d27ae433a.jpg" />
      <p>Hey there! My name is Mike. I live in Montrose, Colorado where I remotely work with Jason and Sam. I am a self-taught graphic designer/illustrator. For several years, I have developed a strong graphic design portfolio and have a collection of my
        journey over the years on my own personal Wordpress at
        <a href="www.mikeyajonesdesign.wordpress.com">my wordpress</a>. I am advanced in Adobe InDesign, Illustrator, and Photoshop. Outside of work, I enjoy working on digital art, reading, photography, and teaching myself how to program. I am currently
        learning web development and python. I look forward to working with my team and I look forward to working with our clients we work with.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about_sam" class="about">
      <h2>Samantha K.</h2>
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/72/1d/13/721d13848e02189b9c7aed0d27ae433a.jpg" />
      <p>Hi everyone! My name is Samantha K. I started as a self taught designer and am now making the big move to pursue a degree in web design. I have experience in affinity designer, html and css. I have a beautiful 2 year old daughter, Emily, and a one
        year old puppy, Tobi. I live in Clifton, Colorado with my fiance, my daughter, our best friend and our dog. I enjoy bike rides, swimming, movies, photography, writing and creating digital art. I look forward to learning, gaining experience and
        working with my team to create beautiful designs.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've tried changing them to max-height and max-width, but they still won't shrink. I also tried omitting them entirely, but I don't want the images to be different sizes. Would it be easier if I just resized them in Photoshop?

Comment: it's not important. Instead of dimensioning the images, consider adding container size. That makes more sense most of the time. Now you will only adjust the container size for the tablet size or smaller sizes and it will be responsive. Good Luck!